# P2P NFC Communication Between Android Phone(Nexus S) and NFC Reader?

Tags: android, nfc, nexus-s, nfc-p2p

I need to establish a P2P connection between my Nexus S and a NFC Reader which is attached to my desktop. Can anybody tell me how to do that. I do not even know how to start.

Please Reply Soon.

Thanks & Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to establish a LLCP channel first, and then use the NPP protocol to actually send/receive the NDEF messages.

LLCP and NDEF are standards published by the NFC forum, NPP is an open standard published by Google. All are available online.

Depending on your desktop reader, some work may already be done. If "nfcpy" supports it, if it has a pn5xx chip, then you already have the LLCP protocol implemented and you just need NPP. I did that for a project of mine and it's pretty easy.

If "nfcpy" does not support it you can try "libnfc" which is starting to support LLCP. Again, you would need to implement the NPP protocol on top of LLCP.

After working out these issues you should watch the youtube video "how to NFC" from the Google guys and study the sample NFC applications on the Android developer site.

Comment: Thanks Andre. The information is really helpful for me. Can you give me some Code level example also.

Comment: Well, both [libnfc](http://www.libnfc.org/) and [nfcpy](https://launchpad.net/nfcpy) are open source and have examples, so you can see the code. I have just submitted a merge request to nfcpy with the NPP support I implemented.